# ClassNotFoundException while starting the Tomcat 7 Server in MyEclipse

Tags: java, tomcat7, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 9 and Tomcat7.0 . I have taken latest code and deployed in Tomcat 7 and started the server. Immediately i got an error log as mentioned below.

```
    INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.aap.apweb.servlet.APServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aap.apweb.servlet.APServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.aap.apweb.servlet.APHTTPSessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aap.apweb.servlet.APHTTPSessionListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/apweb] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/apweb] registered the JDBC driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:53:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13243 ms
```

I think the jars path has to be set. But i am not able to find it.

Comment: Looks to me like the web.xml of the application refers to a listener class, but the actual .class file of that listener is in fact not deployed to the server. If so, the deployment assembly or build path of your application may be badly setup in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this line from the log:

```
The web application [/apweb] registered the JDBC driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

I have added db2 jdbc 1.6 jars(`db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc4_license_cisuz.jar`)to my project build path. These jars solved my problem while restarting the server. It started without any issue.

Thanks for all the geeks to responding me.

Answer (score 2):

Is com.aap.apweb.servlet.APHTTPSessionListener one of your classes? I don't get any hits on Google so I'm guessing it is. You need to ensure that you have set all dependencies in your build path and set deployment policies accordingly. Deployment policies for the project can be adjusted by right clicking on the project, selecting Properties, then going to the MyEclipse/Web page and clicking the Deployment tab. On that tab, you can choose to use the workbench settings (in which case most fields will be grayed out) or not (just deselect the "Use workbench default settings").

Note that the most recent release of MyEclipse gives you more explicit control over deployment, via a deployment assembly. A license for MyEclipse 9 also applies to MyEclipse 2014, which can be downloaded from the www.myeclipseide.com web site.

Comment: i tried your answer but not solved my problem. With your answer i got to know how to find Context root of an application. Anyhow i found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project

then go to **build path** -> **add library** in libraries pane.

then select **server run time** then **add apache tomcat** and then try to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the required projects as jar files and place them in your .WAR file  in WEB-INF\lib .This ensures that your classes from your jar files get loaded during application startup.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when I started tomcat server in Eclipse Luna environment. And my OS is Ubuntu.
Actually the problem is when I build the project the web module not create the M2e-wtp maven folder. When we start the tomcat server it could not see the maven dependencies. That's while the exception came.
I resolve this issue by Downloading the latest Mars eclipse. And again I checked out my project.
After clean installed my project the issue was resolved. It's working fine.